# Retrieve data from Firebase database in values form

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
 mDatabase6 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Region 1").child("Parameter Reading");
    mCO2View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CO2value);

    mDatabase6.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot datasnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String CO2level = datasnap.child("CO2").getValue(String.class);
                mCO2View.setText("CO2: " + CO2level + "ppm");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mCO2View.setText("CO2: Error");

        }
    });
```

I try to retrieve data that will be updated every interval of time, this code is for retrieve data that store in database in string form, I would like to retrieve the CO2 in values form. Pls get a help. Thanks

Comment: can you show me your database nodes please

Comment: sry im afraid that i cant able to be allow to put my image here, however i try to describe database nodes in words form.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1016267395179563&set=a.1016267525179550.1073741827.100003889362289&type=3&theater
I put the link to the picture to show my node. Thanks for help

Comment: did u create a helper class use getvalue().toString();

Comment: no, what i do i just create loop to obtain the string data from the database. I would like to change it to values form instead of string form

Comment: You can get the JSON from your database as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Sharing your JSON as text makes it searchable, and allows other to copy/paste it to test your code, use it in their answers, and in general is a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Please add your database structure.